# How to Select the first time entry, then only times greater than 5 minutes apart

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
 CREATE TABLE import_time
    ( date datetime NUll,
    time datetime Null,
    Employeeid nvarchar(25) Null)

 INSERT INTO import_time (date, time, Employeeid) 
 Values ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 12:50:12.000', '1234') 
  , ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 12:55:00.000', '1234') 
  , ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:25:12.000', '1234')
  , ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:50:12.000', '1234')
```

How would I only select the first time entered then the times that are greater than 5 minutes apart?
The Query should return 12:50, 13:25 and 13:50 not the 12:55 entry

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a `datetime` AND including a time column with no date component?  This is weird.  And if you had `12:57:00` would that be chosen or not?

Comment: The program I am collecting the data from stores the time as a datetime data type. I  am just emulating what I am seeing in a larger database. -Regards B

Comment: @GordonLinoff I saw a number of databases like that back in the sql 2000 and earlier days before there were date and time datatypes. Not saying it was a good plan, just something I saw long ago.

Comment: It's always good to use tags to specify which version of software your are using. This way you can get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the date and time from previous row to each row.
You can use LED to do that. Hope you have SQL Server 2012 and later

You also should be careful for times around midnight, because for those entries, you may get wrong if you only compare the time.

```
;with ct as (
    select [date], [time], Employeeid
    , prev_date = lag([date]) over (partition by Employeeid order by [date], [time])
    , prev_time = lag([time]) over (partition by Employeeid order by [date], [time])
from #time
)
select [date], [time], Employeeid
from ct
where prev_date is null or prev_time is null -- this gives you the first entry
      or datediff(minute, prev_date + prev_time, date + time) > 5
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to check that there's no other row with a lesser or equal time that's within five minutes in the past of the current time, which we get with `dateadd()`.

To decide whether a row isn't the current row you'd need a key. In absence of one in your post I used the undocumented `%%physloc%%` pseudo column as a surrogate. But undocumented means subject to change without further notice, so you want to replace that.

To fix your split date time you can use `+`.

For convenience I use a CTE to prepare the original table into a form more usable.

```
WITH
cte
AS
(
SELECT date,
       time,
       employeeid,
       date + time datetime,
       %%physloc%% physloc
       FROM import_time
)
SELECT c1.date,
       c1.time,
       c1.employeeid
       FROM cte c1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM cte c2
                                WHERE c2.employeeid = c1.employeeid
                                      AND c2.physloc <> c1.physloc
                                      AND c2.datetime <= c1.datetime
                                      AND c2.datetime > dateadd(minute, -5, c1.datetime));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03c7b4d1c95be2587dc75ab30d95a713)

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
DECLARE @import_time TABLE
( 
    date datetime NUll,
    time datetime Null,
    Employeeid nvarchar(25) Null
)

INSERT INTO @import_time (date, time, Employeeid) 
Values 
    ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 12:50:12.000', '1234') , 
    ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 12:55:00.000', '1234') , 
    ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:25:12.000', '1234'), 
    ('2019-05-22 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:50:12.000', '1234')

SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),B.time ,108) 
FROM
(
    SELECT Employeeid,MIN ([time]) EnrtyTime
    FROM @import_time
    GROUP BY Employeeid
) A
INNER JOIN @import_time B 
    ON A.Employeeid = B.Employeeid
    AND 
    (
        A.EnrtyTime = B.time
        OR
        B.time >= DATEADD(MINUTE,5,A.EnrtyTime)
    )
```